# Unable to go to the merchant account on paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have old/classic paypal page without using paypal api. I have a test business account 'satria_biz_cad@gmail.com' on my paypal. but somehow when I click the 'Buy' button, it don't go to the paypal merchant account page. the paypal merchant account page should be displayed with the store name, the amount, the item description, etc. But it show the ordinary paypal page with the login as if its a personal account. there is no store name, the amount, etc. This keep me frustrating. Here is the code

```
<form action="http://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="satria_biz_cad@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="TEST">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="amount1" name="amount" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="custom " value="medium-email">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://project.dev/index.php?payment=fail">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://project.dev/success.php">
<input id="tax1" type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<!--<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">-->
<input style="margin: 0 0 10px 28px;" align="center" type="image" src="http://project.dev/buy.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
```

I'm very sure 'satria_biz_cad@gmail.com' is a business account because I tested it on my another project but use the paypal api. I already check the account many times in developer.paypal.com to make sure it's a business account. What I miss here?
Note: If i change the form action attribute to "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", it'd go to the merchant/business account very well.

Answer (score 0):

as you said satria_biz_cad@gmail.com is a business account only. You were trying a test on BUY NOW button whenever you clicked it redirects to paypal personal account, you want to know why it happened. Kindly clear the cache of you browser and try to log out all the sandbox account. If possible try to run on different browser.